# How do I get specific nodes from a xml Url and list them in winforms

Tags: c#, xml, winforms

I am very new to programming and I've gotten a task to complete with winforms and I have never touched XML before.

I have to get weather data from a XML-file called Urls.xml that has three links inside (example: http://www.yr.no/place/sweden/stockholm/stockholm/forecast.xml).

So far I've managed to get the temperature from the first link in the XML-file to display but I have trouble to get all the temperatures.

My question is: **How do I get the temperature values from all three cities inside the Urls.xml and display them on my winforms app?**

Please let me know if you need any more information, as I've said im very new to programming and I appreciate all help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

The best way in this case would be to use Linq to get the values you desire.

Load the URL into a string and then use XmlDocument to read the string as an XML.

```
    public string xmlURL = "http://www.yr.no/place/sweden/stockholm/stockholm/forecast.xml";
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        string xmlStr;
        using (var wc = new WebClient()) {
            xmlStr = wc.DownloadString(xmlURL);
        }
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.LoadXml(xmlStr);
        XmlElement root = xmlDoc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode node = root.SelectSingleNode("XPathInfo");
   }
```

Read more on:
Some XPath Examples https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx
I would post more, but look up SelectNodes and SelectSingleNode in the MSDN for assistance if you need say, all the location values use SelectNodes or if you want something very specific, just use SelectSingleNode.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I'm just wondering, where did you get "doc." in XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode from?

Comment: @Sten fixed... typeo on my part. I copied some stuff from a program I wrote heh.

Comment: Now it tells me that XDocument does not contain a definition for 'SelectSingleNode'. Am I missing something? I did write down the using directives..

Comment: @Sten I forgot to include the part where you make the root an element LOL sorry about that. Changed, and see if that works.

Comment: No problems, I appreciate the help! Now the 'SelectSingleNode' works but I get an error on 'DocumentElement'. "XDocument does not contain a definition for 'DocumentElement' etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Been 6 days, sorry, got busy. I sat down and wrote it out, so now it's just up to you to figure out the XPath information you require :)

Answer (score 0):

**Q1, how to get the temperature values .**

Variable `r` in below code is your want.

**Q2, how to display them on my winforms app.**

I'm afraid that i can't help you, you need coding this by yourself.

```
    string url = "http://www.yr.no/place/sweden/stockholm/stockholm/forecast.xml";
    var xml = XDocument.Load(url);
    var search = xml.XPathSelectElements("/weatherdata/forecast/tabular//time");
    var r = search.Select(p => new {
        from = p.Attribute("from").Value,
        to = p.Attribute("to").Value,
        period = p.Attribute("period").Value,
        temperature_unit = p.Element("temperature").Attribute("unit").Value,
        temperature_value = p.Element("temperature").Attribute("value").Value,
    }).ToList();
```

Above code are including `XDocunmet`, 'Linq' and 'XPath' you need know. if you don't know, SEE THIS:

- XDocument : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx
- Linq Expression : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx
- XPath : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath